# Kotlin - Generic Conflict in Type Hierarchy

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to build a type hierarchy of query parameters; an object designed to:

- Hold a reference to the value to be queried.
- Generate an expression of the query to perform over the specified value.

The base class is defined as such:

```kotlin
sealed class QueryParam<V> {
    abstract val value: V
}
```

From the base class, I want to be able to sub-class specific query types; for example...

**EqualToQueryParam**

```kotlin
class EqualToQueryParam<V>(override val value: V) : QueryParam<V>() {
    fun <T, R> toExpression(
        property: KProperty1<T, R>,
        projection: (V) -> R
    ): CriteriaExpression<T, Boolean> {

        // equal is bound to KProperty1<T, R>
        return property.equal(projection(value))
    }
}
```

**GreaterThanQueryParam**

```kotlin
class GreaterThanQueryParam<V>(override val value: V) : QueryParam<V>() {
    fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> toExpression(
        property: KProperty1<T, R>,
        projection: (V) -> R
    ): CriteriaExpression<T, Boolean> {

        // greaterThan is bound to KProperty1<T, R : Comparable<R>>
        return property.greaterThan(projection(value))
    }
}
```

**BetweenQueryParam**

```kotlin
class BetweenQueryParam<V : Comparable<V>>(override val value: ClosedRange<V>) : QueryParam<ClosedRange<V>>() {
    fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> toExpression(
        property: KProperty1<T, R>,
        projection: (V) -> R
    ): CriteriaExpression<T, Boolean> {
        
        // Projection in this case doesn't actually make a great deal of sense
        // Ideally the projector needs to be removed. 
        // More than likely in this case V and R are the same thing.
        val start = projection(value.start)
        val end = projection(value.endInclusive)
        
        // between is bound to KProperty1<T, R : Comparable<R>>
        return property.between(start, end)
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have no way of calling `toExpression` from the base class, essentially rendering this hierarchy useless.

I've tried...

- unchecked casts to `Comparable<R>`
- elevating `<R>` to the class level, rather than the function level, but this isn't useful because then the consumer of the `QueryParam` needs to know the implementors intention under the hood (it becomes a leaky abstraction).

Comment: 1. Are you sure QueryParam has to be a sealed class ? 2. Why not put "toExpression" in QueryParam as an abstract function ?

Comment: @AnthonyChatellier Yes, it's sealed because there are a limited number of types in the hierarchy, which will all be implemented up front. The reason that `toExpression` isn't an abstract function in this case is because the function declarations are different. The first has no generic constraints (`<T, R>`) the second has a generic constrain (`<T, R : Comparable<R>>`) and `R` should not be visible at the class level; only `V`

Comment: Either the subclasses share the exactly same inherited method signature and I can use them without knowing the concrete class. 

Either they do not share the same signature and I can't. 

Putting generics at all levels to have an "in between" can be a complexity trap, except if you really really need this hierarchy.